# ordering through an has_many relationship with a condition in rails 3 / active records / postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have two objects, items and taxonomy nodes.

I have a selection of "items" that I want to order based on the alphabetical order of the taxonomy_nodes it is attached to, but only for one particular "top parent", whose ID is provided (as in "i want to sort alphabetically using this parent"). If I understood nested sets properly, you can find out if a taxonomy_node belongs to a certain parent when its left and right values are "within" the left and right values of the top parent: for instance the top node "vegetable" of values left:1 and right: 10 has "potato" of values left: 2 and right: 8 as a child.

An item can have several taxonomy_nodes, and I am using the awesome_nested_set gem to get the taxonomy_nodes to behave like nested sets with a hierarchy. Thus, I can have various main "taxonomies" against which the items are tagged, identified by their "top node".

The only way, for the moment, to identify if a taxonomy_node belongs to a particular "top node" is to use the lft and rght values of the taxonomy_node, and this is where I hit a stumbling block when trying to allow my users to sort the list of items by one of the main taxonomies.

I imagine that the only way to achieve that would be to be allowed to use "conditions" to be applied in the ordering itself, but cannot really how this could be possible!

Ordering with a more simple field, like "item_template", is easily achieved:

```
 @items.joins(:item_template).includes(:item_template}.order("template_name #{sorting_direction}")
```

Here is the taxonomy table:

```
Table name: taxonomies

id              :integer          not null, primary key
name            :string(255)
parent_id       :integer
lft             :integer
rgt             :integer
created_at      :datetime         not null
updated_at      :datetime         not null
depth           :integer
```

the taxonomies are related to items through an ItemTaxonomy object. I am not overly familiar with PostgreSQL, and was wondering if maybe I could write a function to try and achieve this result?

Hope this is clear!

Comment: `sort the list of items by one of the main taxonomies` is not a precise description. Also: Only one level of nesting? If no, then *how* do you use `lft` and `rght` to identify the top node exactly?

Comment: sorry if this wasn't clear: basically I have a selection of "items" that I want to order based on the alphabetical order of the taxonomy_nodes it is attached to, but only for one particular "top parent", whose ID is provided (as in "i want to sort alphabetically using this parent"). If I understood nested sets properly, you can find out if a taxonomy_node belongs to a certain parent when its left and right values are "within" the left and right values of the top parent: for instance the top node "vegetable" of values left:1 and right: 10 has "potato" of values left: 2 and right: 8 as a child.

Comment: OK, I think I understand how your nested sets work. But the sort order you are looking for is not well defined, yet (or I don't get it). You only want to consider `taxonomy_nodes` that fall under a specified "top parent". What if an item has no link to a taxonomy under that parent? What if it has multiple? How to sort then? Also please *edit* your question with these clarifications. The general public would have a hard time to put piece it together from the comments.

Comment: woops sorry I'll edit it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>New version after update.</sup>
You can join your items to their taxonomies and taxonomies must lie within the range of the "top parent" - which can be implemented as another [`JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM). Could be an expression in the `WHERE` clause as well.

Assuming a nested set model as per updated description, where `lft` & `right` are within the range of a superior node.

Also assuming:

- Items without a link to a qualifying taxonomy are *dropped* from the result
- Items with multiple links to qualifying taxonomies are listed *multiple times*.

```
SELECT t.name, i.*
FROM   item AS i
JOIN   taxonomy_node AS tn ON tn.item_id = i.id  -- assuming, no specification
JOIN   taxonomies AS t ON t.id = tn.taxonomy_id  -- assuming ...
JOIN   taxonomies AS parent ON parent.lft  <= t.lft
                           AND parent.rght >= t.rght
WHERE  parent.id = ?    -- id of "top parent" here
ORDER  BY t.name
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot erwin I'll give it a go and will let you know - thanks for taking the time to have a look at this!!